# Facebook API how to allow only members of a group to access the app

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, member, facebook-group

I am currently using this php code.

With the code I am using now I get a few problems.

1. When i log on it only asks for permission to use id/username not groups.
2. I get this error message:
   "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 23" which is the foreach check for the group.

Yes the correct values are set in my code, I just don't want the entire world to know it.

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP ID',
  'secret' => 'SECRET',
));

// Logg ut
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
    $facebook->destroySession();
}

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,groups','GET');
    $user_belongs_to_group= FALSE;
    foreach($user_profile['groups']['data'] as $group){
        if($group['id']===GROUP ID){ // Gruppeid
            $user_belongs_to_group=TRUE;
        }
    }
    if($user_belongs_to_group){
        echo "Good du tilhører gruppen";
    }else{
        echo "Ikke good, du tilhører ikke gruppen";
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you asked for the permission user_groups or friend_groups? user_groups permission for a user's non-public groups /
friends_groups permission for a user's friend's non-public groups (from graph api page on groups)

Comment: Yes i have tried that out on my own account, and when i log on the website with my own account i get all the groups that i have on my account up + i get the correct message "Good du tilhører gruppen", but its like 500 +/- members in the group and i really dont hope i have to manualy add every single one of them?